# $\sum \frac {1}{n^2 a_n}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n\geq 0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges .Show that $\sum \frac {1}{n^2 a_n}$ is divergent

I think that this inequality will going to help me.

$\frac{1}{n^2a_n} \leq \frac{1}{n(na_n)} \leq \frac{1}{n} $

Comment: That inequality won't help.  You would want it the other way around: $\frac{1}{n^2a_n}\geq \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I would think in another direction. $a_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ can be false for infinitely many $n$ but still $\sum a_n$ converge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following inequality as a consequence of the [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cauchy-Schwarz_Inequality):
$$ (a_1+...+a_n) ( \frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}) \geq \left( \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2$$

Since the RHS is divergent, and the sum $\sum a_n$ is convergent, it follows that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2 a_n}$ is divergent.

(By the way, in order to put $a_n$ in the denominator, you must assume that $a_n>0$. This also proves that if $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum a_n \neq 0$)

Answer (score 3):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$ \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\right)\cdot\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}\right)\geq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\geq \log^2 N $$
hence by assuming $a_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n = C$ it follows that:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}\geq\frac{\log^2 N}{C} $$
that is enough to ensure divergence.